# How do I use 'is not None' in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to customize the greeting on my homepage so it's whether:

When logged in and entered first name:

> John! Where do you want to go?

else:

> Where do you want to go?

This is my template:

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated and not firstname_of_logged_user == None%}
 <h1 class="text-center" id="extraglow">{{firstname_of_logged_user}}! where do 
 you want to go?</h1></label>
{%else%}
<h1 class="text-center" id="extraglow">where do you want to go?</h1></label>
                                {%endif%}
```

However, it doesn't seem to pick up the "not None" part because if the user is logged in but didn't enter first name it shows like this:

> ! where do you want to
>   go?

and if I say:

```
firstname_of_logged_user is not None
```

it says an error:

> Unused 'is' at end of if expression.

Seems like an easy thing but it's not working. What's wrong? Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `!=` operator instead of `not`. However, things can be simplified even further to:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and firstname_of_logged_user %}
```

The above will check whether or not `firstname_of_logged_user` is truthy in your template.

Answer (score 20):

The if template tag has supported the `is` operator since Django 1.10 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/#templates)).

You can now do `{% if x is None %}` and `{% if x is not None %}`.

Comment: This is the current right answer.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#is-not-operator

Answer (score 4):

The `is`  operator is not supported. Just use `{% if var != None %}`. This is not exactly the same but it will be sufficient for most cases.

See [supported operators here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#boolean-operators).

If you actually want to use the `is` operator, you would have to implement it as a custom template tag.

For instance:

```
@register.filter(name='is')
def do_is(lhs, rhs):
    return lhs is rhs
```

Thus you will be able to use it as:

```
{% if var1|is:var2 or not var3|is:var4 %}
    ...
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, because you are trying to change a keyword.

Comment: Stupid mistake indeed. I corrected my code, thank you. However, `is` operator is now supported in Django templates for long time. :)